# Approximate irregular signal to square signal

Tags: approximation, electrical-signal

I'm trying to approximate this irregular signal to a square signal because I need to get the amplitude and pulse width of it. Is it possible to do an approximation for it?

[image]

Comment: well, what is the important parameter about approximation. To state something extreme: I could just draw *any* square signal, at any position, and claim it's an approximation, just with some error. Well, clearly that wouldn't help you, but we really don't know what it *important* to you, and there's many things to trade off here (for example,is it important that the integral becomes close to the original signal, or that the peak is completely covered?Onset or final?). By the way, in my understanding, a square signal is an impulse that is as wide as its amplitude is high; is that what you mean?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Hello sir, yes you are right, I forgot to add details.. The approximated signal should have nearly peak of the irregular signal. And it should be rectangle not square, I mean width and amplitude are not required to be same. I'm trying to do approximation because I need to record the pulse width of this irregular signal, but when I use standard way, time interval between 0.5*amplitude to calculate the pulse width, it already out of the simulation time.

Comment: OK; but how do you know whether a width and a height of the pulse are right? What is the way you want to actually show or do with this pulse?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, yes I also don't think it's easy to get an accurate approximation model for this signal. I'm trying to find the relationship of input pulse width/height and output pulse width/height for my cmos circuit, and build regression model for it, so in this way when I have a input pulse, I can use this model to predict the output pulse width/height..

Comment: sorry, you're still speaking in riddles! Your original signal doesn't even resemble a rectangle, and you haven't explained what "width / height equivalent" you're thinking of.